# Failing to get POST params using node.js and express

Tags: node.js, post, get, express

I am quite new to node.js and I love it. I am just trying to get a very simple login to work. I don't have a problem when I try to get the form input data useing GET. But I am sending passwords so I don't want to use GET because of the info in the url.

The form opens /login (admin.login) but I keep on getting a error

> Cannot POST /login

The form is written in Jade what should not be a problem due to that a ends up in HTML anyway.

```
extends layout

block content 
h1 Admin Login
form(action="/login", method="post")#inputFields
    span Username
    input(type="text", name="username")
    span Password
    input(type="password", name="password")
    input(type="submit")
```

this is the file what the login links to

```
/*
 * GET home page.
 */

exports.index = function(req, res){ 
    if (req.session.UserLogin != true) {
        res.redirect("../login");
    } 

    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};


exports.login = function(req, res){  
    req.
  res.render('login', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

Really that is all there is because it does not let me do anything after that.

Thanks a lot 
Jason Hornsby

Comment: Did you add a route which handels POST requests to '/login'? Please post the code.

Comment: Could you please verify that your routes have POST "/do" ?

Comment: I am not doing anything with the data so far it is only the html.

Comment: @Jason can you fix your post (I tried as best as I could...)

Comment: sory... I am new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that you don't have a route set up to handle POST request to login. You seem to be using Express as a framework, so just add a:

```
app.post('/login', handleLogin);
```

to handle the request. You can then have a function to process:

```
exports.handleLogin = function (req, res) {
    //Handle request here
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
}
```

Note that post parameters can be accessed through the req.body object

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, that worked. I had app.get instead of app.post. Didn't know there was a difference.

Comment: Not a problem. For future reference you can check out Express's API reference: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB